# How to handle TaskCanceledException?

Tags: exception, xamarin, task

I have a xamarin app that uses plugins for media access to select or take a photo.

In my relay command I have this:

```
try
{
    var mediaFile =
        await
            _mediaPicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions());

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        mediaFile.Source.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        ...do image stuff here
    }
}
catch (TaskCanceledException taskCanceled)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(taskCanceled.Message);
}
```

Is there a better way to handle task cancellation exceptions in general? The SelectPhotoAsync doesn't take a cancellation token. Is an empty catch ok here? It is perfectly fine for a user to cancel the operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, you should catch `OperationCanceledException` rather than `TaskCanceledException`. Other than that, your approach looks fine; the proper way to handle the exception is to catch it.

Comment: This is an old post, but just to clarify, after catching the exception, should any further manipulations should be made ? Or cancelling a task represent no treats on acquired resources ?

Comment: @scharette: That depends on your application. Normally, I structure my code so that by the time an exception is caught, any resources have already been cleaned up.

Comment: I see. thank you for your time ! your several posts have really helped me understanding  Tasks in c#.

Comment: Just to be sure, would you consider doing nothing when catching `OperationCanceledException` be acceptable. In my case, I'm closing a WPF app which cause to cancel a task. But when I catch the exception I feel like I should do nothing (I dispose ressources elsewhere) does this seems legit ?

Comment: @scharette: If your resources are in `using` blocks, then they'll be automatically disposed. If not, you may want to consider disposing them.

Comment: So if I dispose everything elsewhere, in your opinion doing nothing in the catch of the `OperationCanceledException` section is acceptable ?

Comment: @scharette: Yes. By the time your catch block is entered, all the objects will have been disposed.

Comment: Yes I was not really concerned about disposing objects but more about doing nothing in a catch block.

Comment: @scharette: Generally I don't recommend it, but cancellation exceptions are an... exception. :)

Comment: Haha! I truly thank you for your time, I know Stack is not about opinions, but only fools are not considering experienced opinions. Thanks again Stephen !